# Reduce number of Hadoop mappers for large number of GZ files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, emr

I have a use case where I have 3072 gz files over which I am building a HIVE table.
Now, whenever I run a query over this table, the query spawns 3072 mappers, and takes around 44 mins to complete.
Earlier, the same data (i.e. equal data size) was present in 384 files. The same queries took around 9 mins only.

I searched the web, where I found that the number of mappers are decided by the number of "splits" of the i/p data. Hence, setting the parameters:
`mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` and `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` to a high value like 64 MB would cause each mapper to take up 64 MB worth of data, even if that requires processing multiple files by same mapper.

But, this solution doesn't work for my case, since GZ files are of "non-splittable" format. Hence, they can not be split across mappers or joined to be processed by a single mapper.

Has anyone faced this problem too?

There can be various solutions to this, like uncompressing the gz files and then using above params to have lesser number of mappers, or using higher end ec2 instances to reduce processing time.
But, is there an inherent solution in Hadoop/Hive/EMR to tackle this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You could try using apache pig, it allows combining small files into a single split, see http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/perf.html#combine-files . With HIVE I thing you would need to reinsert into another table with special hive settings, see http://inquidia.com/news-and-info/working-small-files-hadoop-part-3

Comment: How big are the files you are sourcing from on average? Would it be possible to merge some of those files together? Less files to source from should produce less mappers.

Comment: @alexeipab I havent explored pig, but the solutions in the link that you gave are not relevant, since the files are in GZ format in my scenario.

Comment: @Salmonerd The files are around 2 MB in GZ format. Yeah merging is an option that I stated above too. I just want to explore if there is a better option that can be applied directly on the available data.

Comment: @harshit_sharan Pig solution is relevant, as 2 MB GZ files will be combined by PIG into virtual splits, possibly 32 of them into a single split, which is a single Mapper for 32 files, I did this in the past and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. I think this will help you:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-hadoopcombine/

The main idea is to use the CombineInputSplit and CombineRecordReader to create CombineInputFormat. As your files are .gz, they are going to be unzipped and then read by RecordReader into records.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer please? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer